# underscore: groupBy on django timestamp

Tags: django, underscore.js

i have the objects each having `timestamp` field , consist datetime like

```
data1 --> "2014-06-26T11:06:19.315404+00:00"
data2 --> "2014-06-26T08:04:29.755019+00:00"
data3 --> "2014-06-26T08:03:51.008563+00:00"
```

using **underscore.js** i;m trying to group the data by timestamp field like

```
grp_data = _.groupBy(result, "timestamp")
```

**Expected result:**

```
{"2014-06-26": [data1, data2, data3] }
```

**what is happening is :**

```
    {"2014-06-26": [data1],
      {"2014-06-26": [data2],
      {"2014-06-26": [data3],

}
```

the reason of above behavior is  since the each timestamp of `data1, data2, data3` are different because of  `T11:06:19.315404+00:00"` which is appending in timestamp.
that is why data is not grouped expectedly.

Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a function to the groupBy that extracts the date part:

```
    var result = [ 
        { id: 'data1', timestamp: "2014-06-26T11:06:19.315404+00:00" },
        { id: 'data2', timestamp: "2014-06-26T11:06:19.315404+00:00" },
        { id: 'data3', timestamp: "2014-06-26T11:06:19.315404+00:00" }
    ];

    var extractDate = function(datum){
        return datum.timestamp.substring(0,10);
    }

    var grp_data = _.groupBy(result, extractDate);
```